# return several arrays and variables in a function in c++ (like MATLAB)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

How I can return several variables and arrays from a function into the main function in c++? (like MATLAB)

```
float read_mesh(const char *filename){

//I have two 2D arrays and two variables here that I need them in MAIN function

    return vertex,face,nVert,nFace;

}
void main()
{
    //Load model data
    [  ,  ,  ,  ] = read_mesh(name_M.c_str());
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C++

Comment: build a `struct`, with the things you want to return as the data members, and return an instance of that `struct`.

Comment: To return multiple variables from a function, you can either return a struct, or use reference parameters. But your example concerned returning "one" thing, which is an array, so that's what I answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can use std::tuple template to return multiple values from a function and std::tie to bind elements of the tuple to individual variables at call site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> foo() 
{
  return std::make_tuple(1, 2);
}

int main()
{
  int one, two;
  std::tie(one, two) = foo();
  std::cout << "one: " << one << ", two: " << two << std::endl;
}
```

Elements of such a tuple can be of different types, including containers like std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an array from a function, I suggest you use `std::array` or `std::vector`. For example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> read_mesh(const char *filename)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> myvec(HEIGHT, std::vector<float>(WIDTH));
    myvec[y][x] = ...;
    return myvec;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> myvec = read_mesh("");
}
```

Note that `[y]` goes before `[x]` in this example. You can swap the dimensions if you want the other way around.